# How to run Python code from GitHub actions

Tags: python, github-actions

### Introduction

In my project, I want to run Python from GitHub workflow, but when I run it, it shows an error.

### Showed error:

```
Run python ../main.py
python: can't open file '../main.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Error: Process completed with exit code 2.
```

*before I test `main.py` instead of `../main.py`

But he shows a another error :

```sh
Run python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
Valeur out : 311
  File "main.py", line 9, in <module>
    lineSplit = open("log", "r").readline().split(' ')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'log'
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

### The link to the project

https://github.com/MathieuSoysal/bot-area

Someone have the solution to this problem ?

Comment: The problem is not with GitHub Actions, the error says you need to add the `log` file to your project.

Comment: you haven't a log file in your project.

Comment: For what I checked, you need the `log` file as well as a **username** and a **password** separated from space informed on the first line of the file. Example for the log file: https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/bot-area/blob/main/log . Then, the workflow will return an error if the username and password are wrong: https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/bot-area/runs/4874386788?check_suite_focus=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error said `No such file or directory: 'log'` which means you need to add log file to the project